# tensorflow hangs before initializing global variables in joblib

Tags: tensorflow, joblib

I have a multi-layer CNN in CPU `tensorflow`.

I'm using the `Parallel` and `delayed` functions in `joblib` to learn multiple instances of my CNN, trained on the same set of data.

When I try to run this, the program will hang after a `joblib` worker starts its `tf.Session()`, but before any `tensorflow` variables are initialized, and before I get any output from the `verbose` argument of the `Parallel` function.

I don't really know why this would happen. So I am looking for general debugging strategies from other people who may have combined `tensorflow` and `joblib`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the program to work by changing the `backend` option of 
`Parallel` to `"threading"`. Apparently, the `"multiprocessing"` option was creating too much communication and memory overhead when exchanging input and output data.